# Incorrect division result with double value

Tags: java, division

I have a problem doing a division. I have this chunk of code, where this operation must be `40.4239`, but instead i have this result: `0.005595493389623997`
I can understand the amount of  decimals, I have to solve that with decimalFormat, but I can't understand this result...
contTotal is `288975` in this case, so: `(288975/714861)*100 = 40.4239`
Any idea...?

```
int contTotal = 0;  
double result = 0;
    for(DoubleWritable val : valores) {
        contTotal += val.get();
    }
    result = (contTotal/714861) *100;
```

Comment: Try changing type of `contTotal` to `double`. Also `(288975/714861)*100` is not `40.4239` because `int/int` returns `int`. `(288975d.0/714861)*100` is `40.42394255666486`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but I have the same result...

Comment: Then problem lies in part of code which you are not showing us. Are you sure that `contTotal` is `288975`?

Comment: If that's the answer you get, then `contTotal` is 40. If you're certain that `contTotal` isn't 40, then there must be some other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yes, I have chacked that my contTotal is 288975.0, ehit this code: double contTotal = 0.0; 
      for(DoubleWritable val : valores) {
          contTotal += val.get();
         } context.write(claves, new DoubleWritable (contTotal));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this helps, but it really looks like you're doing the division twice, since `(40.423/714861)*100` is actually `0.005595493389623997`.
I would definitely check that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
double z = (288975.0/714861.0)*100.0;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and I obtain this result: 0.00565479758395896

Comment: That's flatly impossible - the calculation shown here definitely returns 40.4239.

Comment: contTotal should be double, not int.

Comment: This is a mapreduce application that Im doing in Eclipse with Java. But the problem is with the division, the other results are ok. I have all my variables with double type and I obtain a wrong value. In dont understand that.